# how to format read only pendrive

Tags: 14.04, usb-drive, format

My Pendrive is of read only format

No delete file option is enabled

I tried GParted the format to option is disabled

Kindly give me some effective command line to format my pendrive

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If the device is readonly, there's nothing you can do. Try to find out if it has some kind of hardware switch that might have set it to RO.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 possible options:

1. The pendrive has a physical lock; mosttimes it is a slider to prevent accidental deleting. We would need to know brand/make/model of that pendrive to be able to tell you if it has one (edit it into your question). Example with a random pendrive (see the "lock" on the side):

[image]

2. You need to mount the pendrive writable. How is the pendrive mounted? If it is automatic when inserting option 1 is probably true. If you manually mount it please provide the mount command; probably it has a "ro" option where you need a "rw".

Comment: Hey, a Kanguru!  I have many of those, and they're fun.  Consider also the third possibility: The drive is damaged and as such during mounting there were errors, hence forced to 'read only'.  If that's the case, there's not really any way to format/edit it.

Comment: Third, most likely option: the drive is damaged and Ubuntu will keep mounting it as read only even if instructed otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In Gparted, use "Create new partition table" option in menu, while having your pendrive chosen. The proper one is `msdos` (read: MBR).  Then apply. 
If this does not work, your pendrive is blocked at hardware level.

Comment: This WORKED FOR ME

Answer (score 0):

The first guess about the "write protect" switch on the usb device is a pretty good one. If you rule that out, the problem probably is in the file system that sits underneath the partitions on it.

You should use fdisk to obliterate the partition and create a new file system on the device. Don't just repartition or make new folders.  Make a partition with, say, ext4. If you open a terminal and run

```
sudo /sbin/fdisk -l
```

If you don't have GPT partition table (the new kind), this should show drives like "/dev/sda" and so forth.

```
Device         Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048  450562047  450560000 214.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda2  450562048 1578741759 1128179712   538G Linux filesystem
```

When you do that, what does it say about your USB drive?  What is the Type column?

Figure out which is your removable drive, it is likely to be /dev/sdc or such

```
sudo /sbin/fdisk /dev/sdc
```

That opens a text based interface, run "p" to see what partitions there are (probably only one now). Type "d" to delete that. THen "n" to start process of creating new partition table.  It is not unusual to allow one partition to consume whole USB stick.

I recognize that most of the time, USB are formatted with a lowest common denominator file system like FAT32 because people to back and forth to Windows or other systems, you can try that.